# gradle is not installing properly in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gradle, ubuntu-16.04

I have to build my project in java. For this i need to install gradle and i am getting an error when i give sudo apt-get install gradle command in source path using terminal.

> Error: The program 'gradle' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
>   sudo apt install gradle.

I have installed gradle using [this link](https://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/09/06/install-gradle-ubuntu-16-04/)
what should i do? please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Install JDK first by:

```
sudo apt-get -y install openjdk-8-jdk wget unzip
```

To verify

```
java -version
```

Then download gradle package

```
wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4.1-bin.zip
```

Create a directory for the Gradle installation.

```
sudo mkdir /opt/gradle
```

Extract the downloaded archive to the newly created directory.

```
sudo unzip -d /opt/gradle gradle-3.4.1-bin.zip
```

`enter code here`Configure the PATH environment variable so that the gradle executable can be directly executed anywhere on the system.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-3.4.1/bin
```

Follow the above steps..